# angular - how to align content to the center of the card

Tags: angular

```
<mat-card id="card">
<mat-card-title>
    login
</mat-card-title>

<mat-card-content>
    
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="email">
    </mat-form-field><br/>

    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="password">
    </mat-form-field><br/>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" style="margin-right:5px;">login</button>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" style="margin-right:5px;">register</button>  

</mat-card-content>
```

I tried this:

```
display: block;
margin: auto;
```

but its now working, any help would be appreciated. I'm new to angular styling

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhKlY.png)

Comment: if it is working what is the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flexbox: center horizontally and vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use this case

```
mat-card {text-align: center}
```

And if you want to set heading in left then use this also.

```
mat-card-title { text-align: left }
```

Answer (score 1):

use `style="text-align: center;"`

I have create a demo on **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-how-to-align-content-to-the-center-of-the-card?file=app/card-overview-example.html)**

```
<mat-card id="card" style="text-align: center;"><mat-card>
```

Answer (score 1):

With  **@angular/flex-layout** it can be done by using **fxLayout="row"** (or column) and  **fxLayoutAlign="center"** attributes as follow:

```
<mat-card fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center">
  // Your content here  
</mat-card>
```